# Tapping is required twice to uncheck table cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

When I load table view with checked cells and I want to uncheck a specific cell I need to tap twice on cell to uncheck it, I guess I know where's the problem but I don't how I can solve this issue?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("daySelected", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.selectionStyle = .None

        cell.textLabel?.text = days[indexPath.row]

            if indexPath.row == 0 && day[0] == true{
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            }


        return cell
    }
}


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }else{
             cell!.accessoryType = .None
        }
 if indexPath.row == 0{
            day[0] = true

        }


    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }

        if indexPath.row == 0{
            day[0] = false

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, not `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`. In there, to just flip the selection status, do

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
      if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark {
           cell!.accessoryType = .None
      }else{
          cell!.accessoryType = . Checkmark
      }
}
if indexPath.row == 0{
        //flip the day bit
        day[0] = !day[0]

    }
self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```

Comment: this solved my problem, but it just created a new one, now when I want to check or uncheck cell I need to tap twice

Comment: If you're going for checkmark, you should probably be deselecting the cell at the end of the method (so you get the nice highlight animation) - I've updated my answer with that code.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` block and replace you `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` block with the following code and tell me if it's working.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

if indexPath.row == 0
{
    if day[0] = true
    {
        cell!.accessoryType = .None
    }
    else
    {
        cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }
    day[0] = !day[0]

}
}
```