# Checkbox in Static Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkbox, uiswitch

I am new to Swift and I am beginning to learn checkbox in table but my table working properly
 I using static cell:

[image]

my Code:

```
 var flagCell : Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.separatorInset = .zero
    tableView.layoutMargins = .zero

    let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor(red: 16.0, green: 18.0, blue: 34.0, alpha: 1.0)
    nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if flagCell  == false{
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            flagCell = true
        }else {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            flagCell = false
        }
    }
}
```

Mark put on through time.

> How can it solve?

I also want to do UISwith si on, checkmarks appear at all Cell

> How can I implement it ?

[image]

Comment: `"but my table working properly"` or not working properly?

Comment: @Mr.Bista marker disappears only when I click сell twice

Comment: @ Коля Дудла yes because on first click value for flag goes true and on second click your else block executes with true condition.And uncheck the checkmarks.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma  I can not figure out how to fix it
how can I fix it?

Comment: @Коля Дудла What is the output you want?

Comment: @КоляДудла This is your solution so far i guess-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506641/tapping-is-required-twice-to-uncheck-table-cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID")
    if flagCell  == false {
      cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else {
      cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
  }
```

And reload tableAfter taping

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   flagCell = !flagCell
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Or you can use another method for cell updating:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       flagCell = !flagCell
       tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
```

Comment: i have a error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cellID - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: @КоляДудла try to use `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` code for getting cell, or add identifiers for all your static cells in `Interface builder` and use it for dequeueing cells